# Applying various effects to images

Tags: image-processing, language-agnostic

I know how to apply two effects to images -- blurring and making them grayscale. However, I would like to expand my knowledge further and learn more things of this nature.

I decided to Google them but found out that I do not even know what they are called.

I would like to ask: **How do I progress further into image processing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image processing is a very big area with many applications.
These applications go from medical imaging, data compression and many
commercial applications like the ones you find in photoshop.
Without knowing where you are going to apply image processing, I assume
that you want to learn for the sake of curiosity :).

Today we have lots of online courses that make learning more easy.
I did an image processing course by Guilhermo Sapiro on the coursera
website that helped a lot https://www.coursera.org/course/images .
The course has already ended but the video classes are also available 
on youtube.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GWCB3pKi2ko ( One about histogram equalization
you can see others on the related videos)
Another source is the amazing book by Rafael gonzales calle Digital Image Processing.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a website solution this is a good guide to how to use the css filter effect: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/filters/understanding-css/

If you're looking for something else, I think more detail on your application is needed.

Comment: I mean I want to lean to to code my own algorithms to apply these effects .. The link you provided helped me to list down all what I need to learn