# Applying greyscale effects to images - Photoshop CC 2017

Tags: css, image, photoshop

The image below has a kind of faded grey look with what seems to be some slight blurring and works quite well as a generic banner image.

Usually I am provided with these images or just find stock images but I'd be very interested in learning how to apply these effects with Photoshop or CSS. I have a feeling that Photoshop is a more appropriate tool.

[image]

The image I'm experimenting with is this:

[image]

It isn't the best image but for my testing purposes at least it's a similar shape and size.

I know I can use things like de-saturation or a coloured layer with a colour blend mode for this sort of thing. However, does the first image look like it has a specific effect or is it just a case of trial and error?

I appreciate this is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17132972/applying-various-effects-to-images).

Comment: Fair enough, I will leave this question open so that I may add to it in future.

Comment: You will probably find that the question will be closed for you without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open your image in photoshop, add a new layer on top of the image, fill the layer with a color of your choice (in this case grey/black) then reduce the opacity of the layer. You will get something similar to what you want. This is a simple trick. It can be done in other ways too with more modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could get the effect by using css blur and overlaying the image with a gray layer with opacity.

You could also just create the effect in photoshop and use that